# Origin of “can” in the sense of ‘jail’

Tags: etymology

When was [*can* (Oxford Learner's Dicitionary 6)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/can2_1)  first used in the sense of ‘jail’?

[Etymoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=can) says the sense of ‘airtight container’ is from 1867, and ‘toilet’ from 1900, but it says nothing about ‘jail’.

Comment: Is "can" used to mean jail? Could you link to a dictionary, I've never heard of it.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Done.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Rarely used in the UK. "Clink" may be the equivalent.

Comment: @WS2 OLD says it is North-American English. Other dictionaries make no geographical restrictions.

Comment: Ah, thanks both. It must be more popular in America.

Comment: @Jacinto It is almost never used in Britain. It is not surprising that Bladorthin had never heard it.

Comment: "Can" is AmE slang for both *jail* and *lavatory*.

Comment: @Mick So presumably the lavatory in a gaol cell is a _cancan_. ;-)

Comment: It does seem pretty obvious that a prison cell (or, particularly imagine one of those isolation, well, cans such as Steve McQueen starts out in in *The Great Escape*) ... it seems pretty obvious you'd refer to it as a "can".  Like, if a slang word for prison was (say) "box", "hole", etc, I'm not really sure if there'd be an "explanation" other than that "it describes the thing in question".  Regarding the question *when* did that slang come about, it's a good question.

Comment: What @JoeBlow said: *it describes the thing*. End of story. This kind of search-for-the-"origin" of an expression that pretty much just means what it says, outright, is a waste, IMHO.

Comment: definitely not contemporary US english.  at least, not middle-aged white male Midwestern english.  I don't think I've ever heard this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OED to the rescue!

The entry for *can* meaning *jail* mentions that it is slang, originally and chiefly from the United States. Its earliest citation is from 1912.

> 1912   D. Lowrie *My Life in Prison* xi. 125,   I was in th' can ag'in, up against it f'r robbery.

As it appeared in print in 1912, it would presumably have been in spoken slang usage before then.

Answer (score 2):

According to the *Dictionary of Contemporary Slang* by Tony Thorne the slang meaning of can for jail is mainly an Australian and American usage and dates back to  the late 19th century:

> - ***[The can:](https://books.google.it/books?id=5He9AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA83&dq=can%20meaning%20%20jail%20in%20american%20english%20slang&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW8IGWwILQAhVCUhQKHWAZDcMQ6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=can%20meaning%20%20jail%20in%20american%20english%20slang&f=false)*** a jail, a prison. ***In this sense from the late 19th century*** the word is more common in Australia and the United States than in Britain.

Answer (score 1):

**The Dictionary of American Slang, Fourth Edition by Barbara Ann Kipfer, PhD. and Robert L. Chapman, Ph.D.**

Also tells us that **'can'** since 1910 means **'A jail or prison; cell'** in slang.

This very source is mentioned here:

- http://www.dictionary.com/browse/canned